# Out of declaration template definitions for template method in template class

Tags: c++, templates

Does anyone know the syntax for an out-of-declaration template method in a template class.

for instance:

```
template<class TYPE>
class thing
{
public :
  void do_very_little();

  template<class INNER_TYPE>
  INNER_TYPE do_stuff();
};
```

The first method is defined:

```
template<class TYPE>
void thing<TYPE>::do_very_little()
{
}
```

How do I do the second one, "do_stuff"?

Comment: Did you mean to declare do_stuff as a member field?  Assuming you actually meant to declare a method, what are its arguments?

Comment: You need to put brackets after do_stuff in the class declaration

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
template<class TYPE>
template<class INNER_TYPE>
INNER_TYPE thing<TYPE>::do_stuff()
{
    return INNER_TYPE();
}
```

See this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swta9c6e(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 29):

```
template<class TYPE>
template<class INNER_TYPE>
INNER_TYPE thing<TYPE>::do_stuff()
{
    return INNER_TYPE();
}
```

Try this.