# Usage of template class with template method in C++

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-classes

I have a class, which have a public templated methods.
This class has 2 strategies of behavior, which i want to pass via class template.

```
template<class Strategy>
class SomeClass {
public:
    template<class B>
    void ProcessType(){}
};

// And do something like this:
SomeClass<Strategy1> sc();
sc.ProcessType<SomeClassType>();
sc.ProcessType<SomeClassType2>();

SomeClass<Strategy2> sc2();
sc2.ProcessType<SomeClassType>();
sc2.ProcessType<SomeClassType2>();
```

But this code doesn't compile. I need to keep usage exact like this (to manipulate just via strategy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
SomeClass<Strategy1> sc();
```

That is a declaration of a function called `sc` that takes no arguments and returns a `SomeClass<Strategy1>`. This is commonly known as a vexing parse (but not the [*most* vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)). What you want is:

```
SomeClass<Strategy1> sc;
```

Comment: thanks, it compiles. But not build. i try to implement this method in .cpp file and it right me linkage error for this method (unresolved external ...).

Comment: i do a such: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886206/out-of-declaration-template-definitions-for-template-method-in-template-class

Comment: @deeptowncitizen A member function of a class template must be defined in the header file. The compiler needs to be able to see the definition in all translation units.